# Is sub-atomic particles (quarks) bunch of compressed photons?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, standard-model, quarks, gluons

According to theoretical physics,protons,neutrons and electrons are made up of sub particles called quarks which are the building block of matter (baryons). what if the quarks are bunch of compressed photons which infinitely expand to release excess photons in form of gluons? When the exess photons (gluons) are released, they are absorbed by the nearby quark and the process continues infinitely.No photons (gluons) are lost due to the short distance between quarks. Now according to my theory,there's nothing like matter in this universe. what we see is just a bunch of compressed photons.my evidence is If matter can't be created or destroyed,then why colliding an electron and a positron annihilate to yield photons?.This clearly shows matter is photons

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to all of your questions is no, but I'll treat them in turn. We'll also be speaking in the context of the Standard Model of Particle Physics, which I only state explicitly for the sake of thoroughness.

First, you ask if subatomic particles are a bunch of "compressed photons". The answer is no, the Standard Model does not model *any* particle as being made of compressed photons. For the record, neither does any other theory of particle physics, like String Theory.

Second, you state that protons, neutrons, and electrons are made up of quarks. This is also untrue. While protons and neutrons are made up of quarks, electrons are not. Electrons are elementary particles, and so, like quarks, they are not made of smaller particles.

Third, you ask "what if quarks are bunch [sic.] of compressed photons which infinitely expand to release excess photons inform [sic.] of gluons". The short answer to this is that they aren't. The long answer is that there is no reason to think that they would be, and it wouldn't even really make sense for them to be, for many, many reasons. Quarks and photons share very few properties (in fact, both being particles with nonzero spin is basically the only property I can think of that they share, which is also true of almost any two particles in the Standard Model). Gluons are also not made of photons, as you assert in the same sentence. Gluons are a different particle than photons, though both are gauge bosons.

Following that, you state that photons are emitted by quarks and absorbed by other quarks. You also claim that gluons are emitted by quarks and absorbed by other quarks. Both of these statements are true: they are how the electromagnetic and strong interactions work, respectively. These interactions are the basis of quantum electrodynamics (QED) and quantum chromodynamics (QCD). However, photons and gluons are, as I've said, different particles, and so these interactions are separate from one another.

You go on to reiterate that your theory is that all particles are made of photons. You haven't really done anything to substantiate this line of reasoning, and it opens up a great number of questions. How do spin-1 particles aggregate to form spin-1/2 particles? Where do the electric charges on quarks come from? Where do the color charges on quarks come from? How are the photons getting compressed? Why would this have any of the properties of a quark, much less all of them? What about the other particles in the Standard Model?

Your only offered piece of "evidence" is the claim that matter cannot be created not destroyed, which is a blatantly untrue statement. Matter *can* be created, and matter *can* be destroyed. In fact, you explicitly name a process in which matter annihilation occurs: electron-positron scattering. Electron-positron pair production is a good and closely related example of matter generation. So long as certain things are conserved (electric charge, color charge, lepton numbers, energy, momentum, etc.), matter can most definitely be both created and destroyed.

The central claim behind your argument exhibits a very common misunderstanding of how electrons and positrons scatter and generate photons, which is oftentimes mentioned in a sentence or two in most Quantum Field Theory textbooks. No, electrons and positrons are not made of photons. The photon didn't come from somewhere where it was "hiding" before the interaction. The electron and the positron simply came together and ceased to be, and a photon was spontaneously created by the interaction. Likewise, a photon can spontaneously decay into an electron-positron pair.

Comment: I would note, a *single* photon doesnt spontaneously decay to an electron photon pair as this doesn't conserve both energy and momentum simultaneously.

Comment: @Triatticus That's an excellent point!

Comment: @Abel Ouch! So much for your theory.
Reminds me of something the ever quotable Richard Feynman once said about "the cat's meow": The cat emits meows, but this doesn't imply that it contains a finite number of them.